# TypeScript - Type constraints to allow only types, or literals and instances

Tags: typescript

Due to TypeScript's aggressive type erasure, whereby type annotations, interfaces, types and generic type parameters are all erased by the compiler, it's difficult to model certain type constraints. Below are examples of what I'm trying to model, and what I've managed to achieve so far.

**A parameter MUST be the type itself, rather than an instance or literal of the type**

This can be solved by introducing `Type<T>` as follows...

```
type Type<T = any> = {
    new(...args: any[]): T;
    readonly prototype: T;
    readonly name: string;
}
```

We can now define a function which constrains the parameter to a type, rather than instances or literals of the type...

```
function fn(p: Type<String>) { ... }

fn("") // not okay - it's a String literal
fn(new String()) // not okay - it's a String instance
fn(String) // okay - it's the String type
```

The reason that `Type` is generic, is so that you can specify any type can be passed in...

```
function fn(p: Type) { ... }

fn(String) // okay
fn(Number) // okay
```

---

**A parameter MUST be an instance or literal, but NOT the type itself**

This is less trivial, and so far I haven't been able to work this out. Given the following function definition...

```
function fn(p: String) { ... }

fn("") // okay - it's a String literal
fn(new String()) // okay - it's a String instance
fn(String) // not okay - it's the String type
```

That works fine, but it breaks when you want to allow any literal or instance, but disallow any type...

```
function fn(p: Object) { ... }

fn("") // okay - it's a String literal
fn(123) // okay - it's a Number literal
fn(new String()) // okay - it's a String instance
fn(String) // okay, BUT should be disallowed because it's the String type.
```

I'm not sure if the second problem can even be solved, however I would like something that aligns with `Type<T>`, but the inverse of it; for example...

```
type InstanceOrLiteral<T = any> = {
    // what goes here?
}

function fn(p: InstanceOrLiteral<String>) { ... }

fn("") // okay - it's a String literal
fn(new String()) // okay - it's a String instance
fn(123) // not okay - it's a Number literal
fn(String) // not okay - it's the String type
```

Equally, I'd like it to remain generic to allow any instance or literal, BUT disallow any type...

```
function fn(p: InstanceOrLiteral) { ... }

fn("") // okay - it's a String literal
fn(new String()) // okay - it's a String instance
fn(123) // okay - it's a Number literal
fn(String) // not okay - it's the String type
fn(Object) // not okay - it's the Object type
fn(Number) // not okay - it's the Number type
```

Is the latter possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first issue can be resolve, by using a conditional type.

```
type InstanceOrLiteral<T, WhatInstancesAreDisallowed = unknown> = 
    T extends { new(): WhatInstancesAreDisallowed } ? never : T
```

Essentually this checks if given generic `T` extends a constructor (which returns the configurable generic `WhatInstancesAreDisallowed`). If so, the allowed type is `never` or in other words nothing (as never is a union of no types). When the conditional type does not match (ergo it is not a constructor) it defaults to `T` as the allowed types.

```
function fn(p: InstanceOrLiteral<String>) {}

fn("") // okay - it's a String literal
fn(new String()) // okay - it's a String instance
fn(123) // not okay - it's a Number literal
fn(String) // not okay - it's the String type
```

Your second issue requires a bit of trick. You cannot simply make `T` optional in your conditional type and default to `unknown` (= union of all types => would always match the conditional type) or `any` (= disables typing => would result in a union of the two options of the conditional type `never | T` which resolves to just `T` => hence would also not meet your requirements). Instead you have to infer the given type of the function call, and pass it into the `InstanceOrLiteral` type. So that the conditional type can work with the actual given type.

```
function fn2<T>(p: T & InstanceOrLiteral<T>) { }

fn2("") // okay - it's a String literal
fn2(new String()) // okay - it's a String instance
fn2(123) // okay - it's a Number literal
fn2(String) // not okay - it's the String type
fn2(Object) // not okay - it's the Object type
fn2(Number) // not okay - it's the Number type
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=35&pln=1&pc=25#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdgZ2AQzgYwgeQE4BkCWwE2yANgDwAqANFAOoAWyw8SqGCAgthACL4IypAPYB3CABMoAXigBXOAGs4YuAD4ZUALAAoKPqiUoEAB5E4EhFADeUOBFEAKAJQAuekxaIU6CFx78gqQi4lIAvlAA-HYQAG7EUO6Uuik6ugD06YZ+wFAAjLoAZgpowPjCcFCFcI5g7qw+GDgERCQUAMrA2PhwAOZqzjZhqdWOAERjg5lQworIIFAAtFCEAORWyFCd3X1QpITEZEU19qJbXT29LlNZs-NLK8DrUJvblyve7BDHjnkATABmG52YS5O4LZZrDZQABycgAtgAjBL7VpHHSjN59YEqMFzCGPZ7ABjQLG9KCgSCpDJZSg5KB-IolMoVKpwP5UNS1JJQABksE+vmaBzanMGtmGaQx7PGkyg03BDyhL3OO3JqMOpGOf0cp1Vl2u8tu+KVT2hZI+bF82t+gOBishZpVcKRKJF6OqOrJONBMxNjqJJP1u0p32lOswiIAVhBSj68fcA1ZidBIzHShTwGHPY4XcjsPG-YnCcmg3mEqGgA)

Comment: This works sufficiently well. Is there a way to disallow `InstanceOrLiteral<any>` as this still allows types? (without using "no-any" in the config).

Comment: @MatthewLayton With this approch sadly not, the conditional type needs the type information of the particular given argument. I cannot think of any other approch.

Comment: Okey dokey. It's still a great solution, so on that basis, I'm accepting!

Answer (score 0):

> fn(String) // okay, BUT should be disallowed because it's the String
>   type.

No, its `StringConstructor` type. That's at least what typescript playground intellisense tells.

Can this work out for you?

```js
function fn<K extends String | Number >(p: K) {

}
```

Comment: That will work for  String|Number literals and instances, but not for _any_ instance or literal. Essentially the constraint should be a complete inverse of `Type<T>`, so it would be like saying, anything _except_ types.

Your example would therefore need to be something like `function fn<K extends Constructor>(p: K) { ... }`